# Print a simple text to a paper in Java

Tags: java, printing

I need to print to the default printer in windows with Java.  I found some sample code on the  internet.  The code compiles without error.  But when ran, I get the following error:

```
**  Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
       at sun.awt.windows.WprinterJob.NullPointerException 
       at sun.awt.windows.WprinterDialogPeer._show(Native Method)
       at sun.awt.windows.WprinterDialogPeer.access$000(Unknown Source)
       at sun.awt.windows.WprinterDialogPeer$1.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)**
```

The program shows the dialog box.  However, when I click on the print button it gives me the exception.  I think this is a case with java Print component.  What can i do to correct this?

Comment: +0.5 for providing the exception message! You're almost there... most likely you're not initializing something, so just post the offending code and we'll try to help you.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to show the printer dialog. Even better would be a [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: http://dforz.net/stuff/TestPrint.java     this is the code .

Comment: nobody going to check un-know web-site, as Howard mentioned, post here SSCCE, that demonstrated your issue

Answer (score 1):

I think that the code is pretty old, but ok. I ran your code TestPrint under NetBeans 7 and Windows XP and it works fine. Have you a printer installed?
What is your configuration? How do you run the compiled class?

[image: TestPrint is running]

When I click on Print:
[image]